# Filter a value relevant to the maximum field

Tags: crystal-reports

Here is my detail field with Order number and Amount.

```
Order Number        Amount
2                   3450
4                   2300
8                   4500
3                   5100
```

Here the latest order is the maximum order number and I need to show it as follows in the report but not all these other records. So here I need to pick up the maximum order number and the relevant value for it. Help please.

```
Order Number        Amount
    8                4500
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this one of the way is to use `SQL Expression Fields`.

Create a new SQL experssion field and write below formula

DB2 syntax

```
Select order number,amount from orders order by order number desc fetch first row only
```

oracle syntax:

```
SELECT order number,amount FROM (
select order number,amount ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY order number DESC) RowNo from orders)
WHERE ROWNO<2
```

Now drag this to detail section.

Note: Above syntax is for DB2 if you are using oracle syntax will change..Let me know if you are using other than DB2 database